# Laravel Livewire won't bind data to model

Tags: laravel, model, binding, bind

I have project in Laravel,

I have model Project - which owns the model Level - with hasMany method

Also i have Livewire - component which updates database with updated() method,

When i want to pass data to Level model, only then i receive null data to server side, i am checking it with dd() method like this:

currently debugging and:

```
    public function updated($propertyName)
    {

        dd($this->validateOnly($propertyName));
    }
```

[dd Fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph9r2.png)

normally it is passing data like so:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLCvz.png)

This null thing appears only when i bind model Level $level directly to livewire component.

If i will slightly change name of livewire wire:model component data is passing through:

[dd changed model name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z496u.png)

I have attached photos, thank you ahead!

I've tried
Different validation rules
Binding model with query builder (it was pain in the a$$)
The right way seems to bind eloquent model